# Azure Pipelines: Exclude folders using Azure App Service Deploy

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines

I have an **Azure DevOps Pipeline** which includes an **Azure App Service Deploy** task (`AzureRmWebAppDeployment`) for deploying an **ASP.NET Core 3.1** project:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Azure Subscription(01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef)'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'MyStagingSite'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'
    enableXmlTransform: false
    enableXmlVariableSubstitution: true
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: false
```

The **Azure App Service** destination, however, contains files in several pre-established folders which are managed independent of the continuous delivery process. We would like to use the *Remove additional files at destination* flag (`RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag`) while leaving those folders intact.

> *Disclaimer:* I don't consider this a best practice and, in the future, we will be moving these files off to a separate storage location. Until then, I'd like to find a solution that will work resolve this.

In **Visual Studio 2019**, we achieve this by excluding those files from our publishing process using the `MsDeploySkipRules` in our `csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  …
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder">
      <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
      <AbsolutePath>wwwroot\\Uploads</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
</Project>
```

This approach works well for Visual Studio. Those rules do not appear to be honored by the `AzureRmWebAppDeployment` task, however, even when using the "Web Deploy" deployment method (`DeploymentType`).

Is there a way to honor the `MsDeploySkipRules` when using the `AzureRmWebAppDeployment` task? If not, if there a way to provide a list of folders which should be skipped or ignored as part of the deployment process? Or, alternatively, if there another task that will permit one of these options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @yang-shen-msft [notes on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60541274/3025856), there doesn't appear to be a way to honor the `MSDeploySkipRules` defined in the `csproj` file. Instead, files and folders can be skipped by defining the *Additional Arguments* (`AdditionalArguments`) parameter of the *Azure App Service Deploy* (`AzureRmWebAppDeployment`) task, [as discussed in another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46961055/3025856).

Since there doesn't appear to be any official documentation for the `-skip` rules, and [the `MSDeploy.exe` documentation that Azure Pipelines references](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd569089(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is out-of-date, the following provides additional details.

First, it's useful to recognize that when you deploy a project via Visual Studio, it's simply taking the `MSDeploySkipRules` configured in the `csproj` file and adding them to it's internal call of `msdeploy.exe` as `-skip` rules. So, given the following rule defined in the `csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  …
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder">
      <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
      <AbsolutePath>wwwroot\\Uploads</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The `-skip` rule is interpreted as:

```
msdeploy.exe -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=wwwroot\\Uploads
```

Translating this to the *Azure App Service Deploy* (`AzureRmWebAppDeployment`) task, the resulting `yml` might look like:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Azure Subscription'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'MyStagingSite'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'
    enableXmlTransform: false
    enableXmlVariableSubstitution: true
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    AdditionalArguments: '-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=wwwroot\\Uploads'
```

> *Note:* Multiple `-skip` rules can be defined on the same `msdeploy.exe` call.

Unfortunately, as mentioned above, there doesn't *appear* to be any official, first-party documentation for the `-skip` rules on `msdeploy.exe`. The [2014 documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd569089(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) acknowledges them, and provides two examples, but doesn't expand on the options. That said, way back in 2012, @richard-szalay wrote a useful article, "[Demystifying MSDeploy skip rules](https://blog.richardszalay.com/2012/12/17/demystifying-msdeploy-skip-rules/)", which provides useful direction here for anyone requiring additional control over their `-skip` rules.